# Can anyone help me identify these logic puzzles?

Tags: puzzle-identification

Can anyone help me find out what these kinds of puzzles are?

## **1. B&W Grid Puzzle**

There's a grid with black & white blocks. A black block will turn white if it's surrounded by 3 white blocks. A white block will turn black if it's surrounded by 2 or 3 black blocks.

*Example*: If the initial shape is a "cross" made by 5 black blocks, what are the possible results given shapes A, B, C, and D? (See image below)

## **2. Foetus Puzzle**

I can't remember exactly how this one works, but generally the contents of an animal's womb is determined by labels depending on the sex of adjacent foetuses.

Rules:

> If foetus A is beside 1 male foetus, A is labeled 1M.
>
> If foetus B is beside 2 male foetuses, B is labeled 2M.
>
> If foetus C is beside 0 male foetuses, C is labeled 0M.

They may be mapped out or have related questions, e.g. "What is probability of getting `1M 2M 0M`?" or "If there are 2 males and 2 females, what constructions are considered impossible?"

## **3. Colored Grid Puzzle**

There is a 3x3 grid and each square must be filled with a certain colour. There are 3 colours (red, green, and blue) to work with, but there aren't necessarily 3 of each.

*Example*: With the following statements, you have to guess which colour is in column 3, row 2.

> 1) The square in Column 1, Row 2 is red.
>
> 2) In Column 2, there are 2 green squares and 1 blue square.
>
> ... etc.

## **Notes**

I couldn't recall the questions in detail but I hope I explained the type of logic puzzles I'm looking for.

[image: puzzle examples]

Comment: I don't know about 2 or 3, but your first example seems to just be a version of [Conway's Game of Life](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiNmZLXiLnJAhVCx6YKHbjECfoQFggeMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FConway%27s_Game_of_Life&usg=AFQjCNFvi4z-ngoRGPyRltoZg2KZNH0bkA&sig2=u9x5fCHb7PAaS-ErOcwi2w)

Comment: I agree with @Irishpanda, the #1 appears to be a [cellular automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton). We have a tag for those ([tag:cellular-automata]) but it doesn't have much variety right now.

Comment: Number 2 sounds like a variation of cellular automata, and number 3 kinda sounds like a variation of the game Mastermind, maybe?

Comment: Thanks guys! It was really worth coming to this site:) BTW is there any special name for this kind puzzles? and where could I get more of these? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

1 is Conway's Life, 2 I don't know, but it sounds like MineSweeper, 3 I think is this, but I don't know it's name:

[image]

The colours tell you how many of each colour are in each row/column, and are in the order red/blue/green/yellow, so they only tell you how many with no indication of position.

I am not sure if the solution is unique for this one, but here's one:

> [image]

Comment: It is not unique, for instance, you can swap the first and second column.

Comment: @CarlLöndahl; yeah i can see that! i might make top-left red as a gven...does it make it unique?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't :-) For instance, you can rotate the lower-right set of 4 squares (green-red) 90°. It is well within the limits of brute-force search. By simply enumerating the permutations of the columns (satisfying the upper restrictions) which is roughly, $(4!)^4$ give or take, you can count them all.

Comment: @CarlLöndahl; so i should look for degenerate patterns. i would write some code, but i'm very busy at the moment with other stuff. the usual size of these puzzles is larger, say 8*8, so any code might get unwieldy.